# Edubuntu presentation template

Tags: edubuntu, presentation

I am a part of a team that try to popularize Linux and free software in academic institutions. I make distribution specific presentations. My duty is to introduce students to Edubuntu.

I wanted to know if there is any OpenOffice.org/LibreOffice template featuring Edubuntu logo/certain Edubuntu bar on top/bottom which can be used for such presentations? Is anyone aware of such a resource? Even in the Ubuntu marketing wiki here

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Presentations#Edubuntu

such a template is said to be under progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether a template exists at the moment however I would personally contact the team directly.

ubuntu-marketing@lists.ubuntu.com

if you explain what you are doing they may be able to get a draft organised for you sooner and they may even want you to join the team to share your expertise and local knowledge with them.

Hope you are successful

Comment: We just started three weeks back and have 3 sessions to our credit. So far we have used SchoolOS http://schoolos.org, a Monofree derivative of Ubuntu specially made for Indian Students. But given the fact that it is based on older version of Ubuntu i.e., 9.10 we have decided to use Edubuntu henceforth. More information about our activities can be found at http://www.fosscommunity.in/wiki/Mangalore/NMAMIT. Our next session for school teachers is scheduled for 26 Feb. 2011.